# How to config babel/babel-standalone with decorator support?

Tags: babeljs

I am using `babel` with browser -> `babel-standalone`
Now I want to use `ES decorator` syntax. But all babel 
doc intro is `babel` for server side, like

```
`
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
`
```

Is any way to client side?

Answer (score 1):

Only recommended for development purpose.  On the client side refer the babel and create a custom preset.  There could be other options as well.  For .e.g.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // Define a preset
  Babel.registerPreset("env-plus", {
    presets: [
      [Babel.availablePresets["env"], { "loose": true }]
    ],
    plugins: [
      [
        Babel.availablePlugins["proposal-decorators"], { decoratorsBeforeExport: true }
      ]
    ],
  });
</script>

<!-- include your file -->
<script type="text/babel" src="script.js" data-presets="env-plus"></script>
```